# Ports not really open after firewalld command

Tags: centos, firewall, docker, firewalld, nmap

OS: CentOS 7

This is a question that is bordering on two issues.  I have a `docker` machine running where I recently installed the PLEX container from `linuxserver/plex`.  The current problem is that I cannot access the site to configure PLEX `https://localhost:32400/web`.  In my attempts to determine why this is occurring, I noticed that port `32400` appeared to be closed even though it should've been opened when the container was created, I am using the host network.

I attempted to see if I could access the site using `curl`

```
curl -i http://localhost:32400 
curl -i http://10.0.1.200:32400
```

I then verified open ports with `NMAP`

```
#nmap 10.0.1.200

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-18 12:52 CST
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.200
Host is up (0.00049s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.10 seconds
```

So clearly port 32400 is not open, so I went to firewall-cmd

```
#sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
  interfaces: eno1

#sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=32400/tcp --permanent
success
#sudo firewall-cmd --reload
success
```

I also checked to see if it was open

```
#sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-ports
32400/tcp
```

However, NMAP still shows its closed.  Any idea why firewalld would show an open port on the docker host machine but it is actually closed?  I'm not even sure this will get the site working for Plex.

---

Verification of what Kramer had suggested that it was possible my interface was not setup

```
# ip addr
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.1.200/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eno1


#firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-interfaces
eno1
```

Comment: I take it you are using `--net=host` in your docker command as recommended

Comment: @sourcejedi Yes, that's correct but it doesn't seem to open any of the needed ports

Comment: A bit on the obvious side, but does `netstat` or `ss` report port 32400 as listening?

Comment: Note that your `nmap` command only tested the 1000 most common port numbers, so there is a fairly high probability that the port 32400 was not tested by nmap at all. Try `nmap -p 32400 10.0.1.200`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the network interface is succesfully added to zone "public", normally only the default net card is (i.e. eth0).
To add an interface with a zone:

```
#firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-interface=<interface_name>
```

To know what interfaces you have try:

```
#ipaddr
```

OR

```
#ifconfig
```

add the interface provinding the IP 10.0.1.200

In the future, when posting the command you run, please also post the output of the command, that helps to understand and debug the problem.

HTH :)

Comment: Updated post to reflect your recommendation, I did verify that the interface was correct but I've listed it out above as well